# Backing up MBR/GPT for detecting boot sector viruses

Tags: linux, partition, backup, mbr

After installing Linux on a computer (Debian in particular), should I bother backing up the MBR or the GPT and use something like monit to periodically compare the MBR/GPT against this backup? Is this worth the trouble, or is there any better way, or is it not applicable anymore?

I recall in the past about boot sector viruses getting into the MBR of a disk and not being able to detect them unless I previously had a copy of the MBR sitting around against which I can compare.

In the past, I've backed up the MBR as follows:

```
# dd if=/dev/sdX of=hostname-sdX-mbr.dd bs=466 count=1
```

For GPT partitions now, I was considering this:

```
# sgdisk --backup=hostname-nvme0nX-gpt.sgdisk /dev/nvme0nX
```

Then re-running these same commands inside a monit task followed by a diff to see if anything changed.

My general partitioning scheme on these hosts is as follows:

- Partition 1: /boot/efi
- Partition 2: /boot
- Partition 3: Encrypted partition

  - LVM

    - vg: Swap partition
    - vg: root partition (/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EFI/GPT partitioning scheme cannot contain malware, so it's not necessary. Monitoring changes in it is still a welcome security measure in case a possible intruder will want to mess with your partitions.

With EFI/GPT the system boots from the `EFI System` partition (FAT32/FAT16) and binary files on it **must** remain the same except for rare GRUB updates and GRUB configuration files.

As for GRUB configuration files: Fedora and other Linux distros which use [blscfg/Boot Loader Configuration specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/BootLoaderSpec/) never change the said files.